# sqlalchemy flask query for many to many

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got a simple sqlalchemy model that I am accessing through flask.

The model is, simplified:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)



tags = db.Table('post_tags',
                db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')),
                db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id')))

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags, backref='posts', lazy='select')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted}')"

class Category(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_name = db.Column(db.String(25), unique=True, nullable=False)
    category_rel = db.relationship('Post', backref='post', lazy=True)


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)
```

To query for users or categories, the code is:

```
@app.route('/categories/<string:p_category>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def category_route(p_category):
    cat = Category.query.filter_by(category_name=p_category).first_or_404()
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    posts = Post.query.filter_by(category_id=cat.id)\
        .order_by(Post.date_posted.desc())\
        .paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
    return render_template("category_posts.html", posts=posts, category=cat,)
```

that works and gives me a paginated object. I'd like to do the same query for individual tags, but am failing. Here's the code that i've tried

```
@app.route('/tags/<string:p_tag>', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def tag_route(p_tag):
    tag = Tag.query.filter_by(name=p_tag).first_or_404()
    x = Post.query.filter(Post.tags.any(name=tag.name))\
        .all().order_by(Post.date_posted.desc())\
        .paginate(page=page, per_page=5)

Gives me 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'order_by'
```

Is it possible to do a many to many query that can be paginated like my categories, somehow? There's mistake in the query I'd think. Thanks

Comment: Remove `.all()` from the query, that's what converts the result to a list.

Comment: Thank you. I tested your suggestion and the query now works as intented. I'd like to credit your answer as solving the issue on the problem with the green tick mark, but the website I am looking at seems to lacks the functionality for this kind of post I think.